# How do I remove certain values from my x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I'm coding a graph for a project i was wondering if i could get rid of the 2,3 ,and 4 that appear on the x-axis so the bars are only on 0, 1 and 5
this is my code:

```
strain_colours <- c("dark blue", "light blue")

ggplot(data = bar_sum, aes(x = conc, y = mean, fill = strain)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = strain_colours) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',
           position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(data = bar_sum, aes(x = conc, ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se),
                width = 0.25,
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                     name = "Caffeine concentration (mM)",
                     
                     ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                     name = "Mean distance travelled (mm)") +
  theme_classic()
```

i've also tried setting the x-scale to discrete, and setting the x value to a string of numbers but it doesn't like that

Comment: Within `scale_x_continuous()`, add `breaks = c(0, 1, 5)`.

Comment: I had just typed something wrong your comment fixed it thank you